# Is every subset of the natural numbers that is closed under successor also closed under addition?

Tags: natural-numbers, universal-algebra

Suppose that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $S$ is closed under the successor operation. Does it follow that $S$ is closed under addition?

Comment: By "closed under the successor operation" do you mean that $s\in S\implies s+1\in S$?  If so, then mustn't $S$ consist of all natural numbers $≥s_0$ for some $s_0\in S$ (well, I suppose $S$ could be empty, but otherwise?)?  Such sets are, of course, closed under addition....but I feel like I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean this question in a first order logic sense?  There are indeed models of Peano arithmetic which contain subsets closed under sucessor, but not closed under addition.

Comment: @JasonDeVito That's true, but the OP wrote $\mathbb{N}$, which denotes the standard model (the natural numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which is closed under the successor operator is of the form $$S=\{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is because as soon as you have an element $n$ in your (non-empty) subset its successor must also be in it, and by iteration all numbers greater than $n$ will be in it as well.

Clearly, any set of this form is closed by addition.

Comment: You have appealed implicitly to the well-ordering principle